# Не создаётся сервер. Проблема с портами

Tags: sql, windows, postgresql, localhost

Не могу создать сервер PostgreSQL. Проблема:

Задаю адрес хоста: `127.0.0.1` или `localhost`

Задаю порт: `8800`.

Но выдает ошибку:

```
Unable to connect to server:
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 8800?
```

Какие методы решения уже были использованы:

1. Брандмаузер отключил, на всякий случай в правилах брандмаузера указал открыть порты.
2. В настройках роутера включил DMZ с указанием порта. Добавил порт в список.
3. Удалил антивирус
4. В cmd проверил `ping 127.0.0.1` - данные идут.

Уже вторые сутки роюсь в интернете, не могу найти решение. Помогите пожалуйста, я уже думаю винду сносить, чего бы очень и очень не хотелось.

[screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hUXj.png)

[screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpSIe.png)

p.s. ОС: Windows 10, использую pgAdmin 4, postgreSQL 10

Переустановил postgreSQL. Теперь создается сервер ТОЛЬКО под портом 5432

Comment: Сервис запущен? Телнет - соединяется?

Comment: Сервис почему-то выключен и не хочет включаться. https://i.imgur.com/d6CaIVQ.png

Comment: Ну так влезь в свойства и разреши, изменив тип запуска, ё моё...

Comment: Переустановил, сервис включен и работает. Но проблема осталась та же. Новый сервер не создается ни под каким портом.

Comment: Переустановил postgreSQL. Теперь создается сервер ТОЛЬКО под портом 5432 @Akina

Comment: Откорректируй postgresql.conf и укажи там нужный порт. Потом перезапусти сервис.

Answer (score 0):

Дорогой друг! Перед тем как что-то делать бывает очень полезно понять что именно ты делаешь. Например настраивать на роутере DMZ для 127.0.0.1 - не самая лучшая идея. Идея использовать для SQL сервера порты вроде 80, 88, 8080, 8800 - не менее удалена от идеала.

Верните настройки роутера назад! Пакеты на 127.0.0.1 не покидают локальную машину по определению. И никогда. Совершенно никогда не попадут на роутер.

Используйте другой порт. Или, как минимум, убедитесь что данный порт свободен и не используется другим сервисом. А он таки, как правило, используется для веба или прокси.

А еще я бы Вам рекомендовал использовать под эксперименты виртуальную машину. Благо хипер-В доступен во всех виндоувсах. Тогда если Вы и наворотите как сейчас, исправление и запуск чистой машины займет пару минут.

Comment: DMZ настроен на 192.168.1.3 [screen1]
Порт проверил, 8800 не используется.

Comment: Я совершенно не понимаю зачем Вы вообще взялись за роутер и ДМЗ. Равно как и то, для чего было нужно менять порт. 

Вы выше пишите что подключаться уже получается.